# how to "conditionally compile" python

Tags: python, windows

Yes, I know, but it was the only way to summarize what I want to do.

For opening a serial port I want to use:

```
    portfd = os.open(portname, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NONBLOCK)
```

Problem is that O_NONBLOCK doesn't exist under windows, which means it blows up here. I'm testing under windows for deployment under an OS that supports non block.

So what I really want is for the O_NONBLOCK to go away or have it #defined for the windows environment with 0 so that I can go about my business without having an error.

Any ideas?

PS: Please don't explain about how python compiles/interprets. I get it, but I'm trying to communicate an idea.

Comment: just try: use `try:`, catch the exception and use the supported flag

Comment: Re your edit: If you ask about conditional compilation and `#define`s in Python, you clearly don't realize the full extend of Python's evaluation model, in particular the dynamicness.

Comment: yeah, the "dynamicness" is probably still sinking in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another method nobody has yet suggested:

```
portfd = os.open(portname, os.O_RDWR | getattr(os, 'O_NONBLOCK', 0))
```

This is the easy way to default any attribute that might not exist.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a try/except block e.g.

```
try:
    options = os.O_RDWR | os.O_NONBLOCK
except NameError:
    options = os.O_RDWR

portfd = os.open(portname, options)
```

This is using the Python approach that it's easier to ask for forgiveness than for permission.

Comment: why -1? It's the Pythonic way... better would be, however, to do it `try: nb = os.O_NONBLOCK; except NameError: nb = 0; portfd = os.open(portname, os.O_RDWR | nb);` (bad that there is no formatting in comments, but I'm sure you know what I mean...)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously there's no compile time/runtime distinction. What you can do is check the value of `sys.platform`.

Answer (score 0):

Check `sys.platform` or `os.name`.

Answer (score 0):

1. What are you doing that you really need the low-level `os.open` API? What are you going to do on an OS that doesn't support O_NONBLOCK? If the subsequent code doesn't actually depend on the O_NONBLOCK property of what you're opening, then is this just an optimization, or what?
2. You could check the environment by examining the `os.name` string.
3. You could apply EAFP.

For example:

```
def file_mode_for_funky_special_purpose():
    try: return os.O_RDWR | os.O_NONBLOCK
    except AttributeError: return # whatever it is that you want for other systems

portfd = os.open(portname, file_mode_for_funky_special_purpose())
```

Comment: 1. Reading the serial port. This is what the docs recommend. To be honest, I'm not really sure why I need the O_NONBLOCK because while I find documentation that it's only Unix, I find no docs as to what it means. I'm assuming it means don't block the I/O for the open, which I don't really need, but was in the code that I'm copying.